# Cannot upload image in meteor using cfs:s3 package

Tags: file-upload, meteor, amazon-s3

I am using Meteor.js with Amazon S3 Bucket for uploading and storing photos. 
I am using the CollectionFS package and Meteor-CollectionFS/packages/s3/.

However, there is no error or response displayed when I try to upload the file.

Client side event handler:

```
'change .fileInput': function(e, t) {
    FS.Utility.eachFile(e, function(file) {
        Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("fileObj id: " + fileObj._id);
                //Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: imagesURL});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Client side declaration

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.S3("imageStore");

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
stores: [imageStore],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
        }
    }
});
```

Server Side

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.S3("imageStore", {
    accessKeyId: "xxxx",
    secretAccessKey: "xxxx",
    bucket: "mybucket"
});


Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [imageStore],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
        }
    }
});
```

Anyone has any idea what happens?